# Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 failed to partition the selected disk

Tags: dual-boot

First time installing Ubuntu, I have C: drive partition, D: drive partition, a system reserved one and 100 GB free unallocated space. I have put Ubuntu installation on USB flash drive and I am getting this error after choosing to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 : Failed to partition the selected disk. I am using the newest version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Don't choose Install Ubuntu alongside Windows -
Choose Something else  - install  Ubuntu this way :

Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Select 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.

Open GParted and select the mentioned unallocated space of the disk.
Create a new partition - format it with ext4 - a size that fits your needs.
Create a new partition - format it with swap - a size matching the RAM.

On the desktop click Install Ubuntu, choose Something else.
Select the new partition you had created for Ubuntu before.
Select **/** as mount point and ext4 file system for formatting.

Note : I assume that Windows is installed in EFI mode, in case it is installed in MBR (legacy BIOS) mode ... 
first create an extended partition and then under that the ext4 and the swap partition.

Comment: Trying it now!!

Comment: Just curious, has installing alongside Windows ever worked?

Comment: @daltonfury42 It works well in most cases. I always use it. I do not agree with this answer at all.